# Diagnosing errors in StreamAnalytics Jobs

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

I've got a series of services that generate events that are being written to an Azure Event Hub. This hub's connected to a StreamAnalytics Job that takes the event information and writes it to an Azure TableStorage and DataLake Store for later analysis by different teams and tools.

One of my services is reporting all events correctly, but the other isn't, after hooking up a listener to the hub I can see the events are being sent without a problem, but they aren't being processed or sent to the sinks on the job.

On the audit logs I see periodic transformation errors for one of the columns that's written to the storage, but seeing the data there's no problem on the format, and I can't seem to find a way to maybe look at the troubled events that are causing this failures.

The only error I see on the Management Services is

> We are experiencing issues writing output for output TSEventStore right now. We will try again soon.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there may be two issues:
1) The writing to the TableStorage TSEventStore  is failing.
2) There are some data conversion errors.

I would suggest trying to troubleshoot one at a time. For the first one, are there any events being written to the TSEventStore? Is there another message in operations logs that may give more detail on why writing is failing?

For the second one, today we don't have a way to output events that have data conversation errors.  The best way is by outputting the data only to one sync (data lake) and looking at it there.

Thanks,
Kati

Comment: Yes, all events from service 1 are being written to TSEventStore. I've been trying to look into the events stored in the DataLake but there are several hundred being generated daily (subject for another question, why are there so many files being generated) So I haven't been able to see if the entries are there. Trying to view the operations log, Azure Portalps crashing